# Rocket.Chat REST API authentication when using "iframe auth"

Tags: mongodb, rest, iframe, rocket.chat

I'm using the Rocket.Chat REST API for some automated user management. This was working great after I installed Rocket.Chat and my admin user had a username/password combo. Then, I activated the ["iframe authentication"](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/iframe-integration/authentication/) system in the admin panel. Now, when I try to use the REST API "login" endpoint, I get the error "User has no password set". Any ideas why this is happening? When I look at the user document in the MongoDB for Rocket.Chat, there is no "password" field (seems to have been deleted when I activated the iframe authentication).

**UPDATE:** I disabled the "iframe authentication" system and set a new password on my account. Looking at the DB now, that user has a "password" entry, so the password is there. But, now I can't log in because it says my password is incorrect. In summary, this software has a lot of bugs, it seems.